# In a Code::Blocks project - have source code files reside in a "src" folder

Tags: ide, codeblocks

I need to use Code::Blocks on one of my machines to work on some C and C++ code. So I installed it. It works great.

Something that I noticed was that the source code resides in the root of the project along with config files and other stuff. This is unlike other IDEs where you have a "src" sub-folder that contains the source code, a "doc" or "docs" folder where you you could put some text files and so on.

**For the sake of unification with other projects, setups and the general rules that we follow in our company (and for other reason not important for this question) I would like to be able to have a "src" sub-folder where I put all source code. I want this to be the location from where the IDE will read the tree structure for the Workspace/Project_name/Sources browser.**

I looked at the config XML files but couldn't find any specific option that will allow me to relocate the source code tree.

I know that I can just create the "src" folder, put the "main.c" files, etc. but that doesn't look like the right way of doing it. When you start opening the source files it prepends all with "src/..." - that's the least.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and (from the context menu) uncheck "Project tree -> Categorize by file type"